# L'Hospital Rule Limit

Tags: limits

[image]
I have taken derivative 2 times and still get infinity/infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying L'Hopital's rule once, you get\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2^+}\frac1{\left(x-\frac\pi2\right)(\sec^2(x))}&=\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2^+}\frac{\cos^2(x)}{x-\frac\pi2}\\&=\overbrace{\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2^+}\cos(x)}^{\phantom{0}=0}\times\overbrace{\lim_{x\to\frac\pi2^+}\frac{\cos(x)}{x-\frac\pi2}}^{\phantom{-1}=-1}\\&=0.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I would Substitute $$t=x-\frac{\pi}{2}$$